# Appearance of NavigationBar

Tags: uicollectionview, navigationcontroller

This is my very first question to the helpful group of stackoverflow.com
Please bear with me if question framing is cumbersome!!

I have a `collectionView(in a ViewController)`,embedded in a `NavigationViewController`.

I have used `didSelectItemAtIndexPath` for each of the `collectionView` cells, linking them to different `viewControllers`,say `VC1,VC2 etc`
I have hidden the Navigation bar, in the `ViewController` containing the `collectionView`, using the code

```
self.navigationController?.navigationBar.hidden = true
```

In each of `VC1,Vc2.....,` I have tried to `unhide` the `navigationBar` using the code,

```
self.navigationController?.navigationBar.hidden = False
```

During simulation, `using xCode`, the navigation bar appears only in `VC1`, but not in `VC2,VC3....`

Comment: Please show your codes.Whatsoever you have tried so far.

Comment: **false** not **False**, right? is it a typo?

Answer (score 0):

From the details you provided it is hard to guess what is exactly the issue.

The navigation controller will remember its status, as long as you use `push` segues, it should stay hidden, unless you set it to show again. You can set it to be hidden before you perform the transition, say in `didSelectItemAtIndexPath`.

To hide the navigation controller, you can use:

```
navigationController?.setNavigationBarHidden(true, animated: true)
```

and to show it

```
navigationController?.setNavigationBarHidden(false, animated: true)
```